# How to resolve ERROR 1004 copy method of worksheet class failed in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Could you help me to resolve:

> error 1004 - copy method of worksheet class failed.

I am getting error on this line "Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)"
Here is the code -

[image]

Comment: Please add the code itself to the question, not just an image of the code.

Comment: Does it fail on the very first sheet it tries to copy, or on a specific sheet?  If it is a specific sheet, is there something "funny" about that sheet?

Comment: Consider setting an object reference to the workbook returned by `Workbooks.Open` instead of referring to it via ActiveWorkbook. Also, check if either workbook (source/destination) has any hidden sheets. If you can refer to the sheet by name (rather than index), try it.

Comment: Is is wise to copy all worksheets from all workbooks in a folder to ThisWorkbook? You can't tell which Worksheet from which workbook afterwards. Worksheets with same name will just had ` (#)` appended. ThisWorkbook will become a huge mess - Names/Styles count increases may make Excel so slow.